# How atomic are SQL transactions really in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

I wonder — if I have have an SQL transaction where in one statement I do a select query, and then in a later statement an update query, is it guaranteed that nothing has been changed by outside factors in between the two?

- So I select a number of rows ⟵ in the transaction
- Another procedure changes one of the rows ⟵ outside the transaction
- Than I want to do the update ⟵ in the transaction

So can this happen? I know the total transaction either happens or it doesn't, but are all individual statements in 1 transaction also executed as 1 atomic unit where nothing can happen in between two different statements? Or is the only way to ensure that the database is locked in between the two statements by setting a manual table lock?

This problem is about this by the way: I transfer money from one user (the buyer) to another (the seller). However, the buyer already deposited money when placing the buy order. Now he may cancel this buy order at any moment. I will then give him back the deposited money. So now it can happen that I'm in the process of transferring the deposited money from the buyer to the seller, while the buyer cancels his order, and I give him back his money. So now the money is given to the buyer, AND to the seller. This requires some high level isolation right?

Comment: The `A` in acid has a very specific meaning. Which is different from how you are using it. Your question is about isolation.

Comment: Oh oke. Well im very new to this stuff so excuse me:p Anyway, do you have any idea's as the answer to this question?

Comment: The SQL standard guarantees that if you run at SERIALIZABLE isolation (the default), then your transaction will not see any effects from any other transaction.  If you run at lower isolation levels, you are no longer as well protected.  The secondary question, then, is "How well does MySQL adhere to the SQL standard in this area?" which is not so clear.  If you use ISAM storage, you may well not get as good protection as if you use InnoDB, for example.  At that level of detail, I defer to people who know more about MySQL than I do.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on transaction isolation level. 
Default isolation level on all of databases I have ever used is Read Committed and this level allows to see changes made by other committed transactions.
 In contrast Serial or Snapshot isolation levels isolate current transaction from others but it does not scale as good as Read Committed.
You can change isolation level per transaction or globally on all of modern databases but I would not suggest to do it without a very good reason, Read Committed is a good isolation for typical use cases because it needs no locking for reads, Serial isolation uses heavy locking to make transactions serial instead of concurrent  and it might not scale for typical uses cases.

Comment: Oke thanks. I just read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems). It does seem like I need Serializable level, because that's the only level where phantom reads are completely ruled out if I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes, but I suggest to change default level per transaction if you need it for some specific use case, global setting to "serial" will kill concurrency. e.g. "SET TRANSACTION ..." or "ALTER SESSION ..."

Comment: I think you can always change SQL statement ordering in application to avoid serial transaction execution level